# How can I summarize my dataset so that the aggregate function takes into account values from another only once?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to aggregate column a with `sum()` and column b with `mean()` but for this `mean()` same values of ID column should be used only once. So that i get sum(3,4,5,6) and mean(7,8,9). How do i write this condition within a `summarize()`?

```r
library(dplyr)
data = tibble(ID=c("111", "111", "222", "333"), a=c(3,4,5,6), b=c(7,7,8,9))
```

###### Edit:

```r
data = tibble(ID=c("111", "111", "222", "333", "444"), a=c(3,4,5,6,7), b=c(7,7,8,9,7))
```

Another ID e.g. '444' can also have value 7. For this case I would want mean(7,8,9,7).

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate `sum(a)` and `mean(b)` separately and column-bind them.

```r
bind_cols(
  data %>% summarise(a = sum(a)),
  data %>% distinct(ID, b) %>% summarise(b = mean(b))
)
```

Or you could use `tapply` + `unique`:

```r
data %>%
  summarise(a = sum(a), b = mean(unlist(tapply(b, ID, unique))))
```

###### Output

```
# # A tibble: 1 × 2
#       a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    18     8
```